# Couldn't rename field in python list (key, value structure)

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, dictionary

I have below list with nested lists (sort of key,values)

```
inp1=[{'id': 0, 'name': 98, 'value': 9}, {'id': 1, 'name': 66, 'value': 8}, {'id': 2, 'name': 29, 'value': 5}, {'id': 3, 'name': 99, 'value': 3}, {'id': 4, 'name': 15, 'value': 9}]
```

Am trying to replace 'name' with 'wid' and 'value' with 'wrt', how can I do it on same list?

My output should be like

```
inp1=[{'id': 0, 'wid': 98, 'wrt': 9}, {'id': 1, 'wid': 66, 'wrt': 8}, {'id': 2, 'wid': 29, 'wrt': 5}, {'id': 3, 'wid': 99, 'wrt': 3}, {'id': 4, 'wid': 15, 'wrt': 9}]
```

I tried below, but it doesn't work as list cannot be indexed with string but integer

```
    inp1['name'] = inp1['wid']
    inp1['value'] = inp1['wrt']
```

I tried if I can find any examples, but mostly I found only this for dictionary and not list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to iterate each item, and remove the old entry ([`dict.pop`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.pop) is handy for this - it removes an entry and return the value) and assign to new keyes:

```
>>> inp1 = [
...     {'id': 0, 'name': 98, 'value': 9},
...     {'id': 1, 'name': 66, 'value': 8},
...     {'id': 2, 'name': 29, 'value': 5},
...     {'id': 3, 'name': 99, 'value': 3},
...     {'id': 4, 'name': 15, 'value': 9}
... ]
>>> 
>>> for d in inp1:
...     d['wid'] = d.pop('name')
...     d['wrt'] = d.pop('value')
... 
>>> inp1
[{'wid': 98, 'id': 0, 'wrt': 9},
 {'wid': 66, 'id': 1, 'wrt': 8},
 {'wid': 29, 'id': 2, 'wrt': 5},
 {'wid': 99, 'id': 3, 'wrt': 3},
 {'wid': 15, 'id': 4, 'wrt': 9}]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping!

Answer (score 2):

```
def f(item):
    if(item.has_key('name') and not item.has_key('wid')):
        item['wid']=item.pop('name')
    if(item.has_key('value') and not item.has_key('wrt')):
        item['wrt']=item.pop('value')
map(f,inp1)
```

Output:

```
[{'wrt': 9, 'wid': 98, 'id': 0}, {'wrt': 8, 'wid': 66, 'id': 1}, {'wrt': 5, 'wid': 29, 'id': 2}, {'wrt': 3, 'wid': 99, 'id': 3}, {'wrt': 9, 'wid': 15, 'id': 4}]
```